# Удаленная отладка Visual Studio 2017

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2017

Для отладки приложений *Visual Studio 2015*, развернутых на других компьютерах я пользовался удаленным отладчиком *Remote Debugger Visual Studio 2015*. Сейчас, решил перейти на *Visual Studio 2017*, все успешно, проекты работают и все собирается. Но вот я что-то не могу найти удаленный отладчик для новой версии среды разработки, где искать? Данного функционала еще нет? В самой *VS2017* есть пункты <kbd>Debug</kbd>=><kbd>Attach to Process...</kbd> но где взять сам отладчик, для установки на сервер?

На MSDN нашел утилиты для отладки только для 2012, 2013 и 2015 версии: [Remote Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx)

Для справки, установлена: *Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition*
Удаленный сервер, где ранее был установлен удаленный отладчик для *VS2015* и успешно работал с ней в паре: *Microsoft Windows Server 2012*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При установке пункт меню не был создан. Но отладчик нашелся там же, где он был у предыдущих версий - по пути `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64` (ну и соответственно х86-версия рядышком).  Сам он есть, просто ярлык не создается. Достаточно скопировать папку x64/x86 на удаленную машину и запустить с правами администратора файл **msvsmon.exe**

Comment: Ага, и вправду все на месте есть, вопрос в том, как мне это использовать на удаленной машине? Ну, я имею в виду установку на удаленной машине самого средства отладки? Я не могу на сервер накатить всю IDE, а вот небольшую программу в виде удаленного отладчика - вполне могу, то что я привел в ответе со ссылками на скачивание.

Comment: как и всегда - копируем папку x64/x86 на удаленную машину и запускаем `msvsmon.exe`

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, приму как верный, вместо этих долгих поисков. Сразу не сообразил, что могу отсюда взять, получается и искать не нужно, все есть.

Comment: Очень долго искал, везде ссылки битые. Спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

После долгих поисков на MSDN удаленного отладчика для *Visual Studio 2017* нашел одну довольно-таки интересную статью: [Remote Debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging), опубликованную 4 ноября 2016 года. Там есть пункт: <kbd>Download and Install the Remote Tools</kbd> - это именно то, что нужно. Переходим по ссылке на страницу [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-rc), там находим пункт: <kbd>Tools for Visual Studio 2017</kbd>, раскрываем список и находим <kbd>Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2017</kbd> и скачивает отладчик нужной версии кликнув на кнопку <kbd>Download</kbd> напротив пункта меню.

Поиск через поисковые системы [Google](https://www.google.ru/) и [Yandex](https://www.yandex.ru/) результатов не дал, сумел найти только во внутреннем поиске [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=Remote%20Debugging%202017&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2). Надеюсь данный вопрос и ответ будут полезны другим участникам.